# Accessing a defined constant returns messed up characters

Tags: php

This is strange I have a constant defined as such:

```
define("RJ_FILES_PATH", RJ_SITE_DIRECTORY."\assets\files\\");
```

However when I try to access the constant in code I get this weird result on my localhost..

```
C:\wamp\www\my.app\assetsiles\2688
```

The `\f` is replaced by a square indicating it as an unrecognised character. Whats happening because of this I am unable to save files to the folder the constant is supposed to point to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes before the `a` and the `f`:

```
define("RJ_FILES_PATH", RJ_SITE_DIRECTORY."\\assets\\files\\");
```

Otherwise they're interpreted as escape codes, since they're within a string. (Just like `\n` is a newline, et cetera.)

Answer (score 1):

You could—and probably *should*—just use forward slashes (`/`) in your file/directory paths. PHP will automatically convert them to the value of the built-in system-dependent constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` when using the string as a file path. This is by far the most cross-platform method of doing it.

Alternatively, you could use single quotes. They interpolate backslashes (`\`) differently in that most escapes are ignored and just interpreted literally (the exceptions being `\\` and `\'`).

```
#                                                       *
define('RJ_FILES_PATH', RJ_SITE_DIRECTORY.'\assets\files\\');
# * still need an escape here because of \'
```

Comment: This is referring to the actual path - I tried using relative paths but it wouldn't work as I expected

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the backlash by double it: \
In my opinion, you always should use '/', because it work fine in windows and linux. In php, there's a constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR but it's uneccesary because '/' work fine.